# Adding <li> to every item on html5 drag and drop

Tags: html, html-lists

I have a HTML5 drag and drop function. You can drag an item from div1 to div2.
What I want to do is for every item dropped into div2, automatically give it a list number.
At the minute the JS code for adding the text to div2 looks like this:

```
function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    ev.target.appendChild( document.getElementById(data));
}
```

Above drops the element into div2. 
Below describes the drag function.

```
function drag(ev) {
ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
}
```

The html looks like this:

```
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)">
<div id="title" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" style="font-family:Metacopy">Text to be Dragged</div>
</div>
<div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)"></div>
```

I'd be grateful for any help. Sorry if the answer is glaringly obvious, I'm kind of new to this.

Comment: Do you know how to use jsfiddle? ( http://jsfiddle.net ) It's faster to post the working code you have so far there, this way you can receive an answer with a jsfiddle edit, containing code that does what you need. Anyway, what do you mean by 'list number'? Do you need some sort of counter for the dragged items?